# Rotation of collision bounds

Tags: java, collision

I'm working on my 2D java game and I have a problem with rotation of collision bounds.

I have an Attack Class:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(player.getDir()), (double) player.getX() + 16, (double) player.getY() + 16);
    g2d.setComposite(makeTransparent(alpha));
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, 32, 32);
    g2d.setComposite(makeTransparent(1));
    g.setColor(Color.red); // drawing the results
    g2d.draw(getBounds()); // drawing the getBounds();
    g2d.setTransform(old);

}

private AlphaComposite makeTransparent(float alpha) {
    int type = AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER;
    return (AlphaComposite.getInstance(type, alpha));
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {

    return new Rectangle((int) x, (int) y, (int) width + 32, (int) height + 32);
}
```

[image: Sample of result]

But in practice it only "deals damage" to the right of the character - like no rotation happens. I was trying to use: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5925715/5502471
solution, but I kinda failed and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Few hints:

- Attack is a seperate class,
- Attack is caused from a Player Class by Keyboard input,
- Collision happens in enemy class,

  ```
  if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Attack){
      if (getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){
          health-=3;
      }
  }
  ```

I was looking for some "easy" way to do it, since I was hoping to use this in many many things ;) If there is no easy way, then the hard way will do too - challenge accepted!

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty simple solution (somewhere at stackoverlow.com ;P). It's not perfect but, well, at least it works ;). Just useing a method to move around the starting point of drawing the rectangle bounds.

```
 public Rectangle getBounds() {

        double newX = 0;
        double newY = 0;
        Rectangle attack = new Rectangle((int) newX, (int) newY, 32, 32);

        double[] pt = { x, y };
        AffineTransform
                .getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(player.getDir()), (double) player.getX(), (double) player.getY())
                .transform(pt, 0, pt, 0, 1);
//playeer.getDir() - method to return the rotation angle in degress
        newX = pt[0];
        newY = pt[1];

        attack = new Rectangle((int) newX, (int) newY, 32, 32);

        return attack;
    }
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjd0a.png)

I hope you find out it usefull. Cheers!